# Jupyter notebook just could not to serve for remote access

Tags: jupyter-notebook, remote-access

I'm configuring jupyter notebook on a linux server(Red Hat 4.8.5).I want to use a remote client to visit jupyter notebook.

#### First of all,I generated a config file:

```sh
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

#### And then I modified the config file `/root/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`:

```sh
c.NotebookApp.ip="0.0.0.0"
c.NotebookApp.allow_origin='*'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser=False
c.NotebookApp.password=u"sha1:16715d2ac300:ee938c81001cfd0841f8bf1441bd02038b62965e"
c.NotebookApp.port=9999
c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir='/home/jupyter_notebook'
```

#### Finally,I run the jupyter notebook:

```sh
jupyter notebook --config /root/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py --allow-root
```

#### However,The jupyter was just running the server at localhost:

```sh
[root@localhost home]# jupyter notebook --allow-root --config /root/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py 
[I 18:22:45.287 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/jupyter_notebook
[I 18:22:45.287 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 18:22:45.287 NotebookApp] http://(localhost or 127.0.0.1):9999/
[I 18:22:45.287 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

#### When I use the same config file to run jupyter notebook on my Aliyun server(Ubuntu 16),it worked:

```sh
[I 17:48:59.388 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/jupyter_notebook
[I 17:48:59.388 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 17:48:59.389 NotebookApp] http://(iZbp14dhkm7uc5lnu5j510Z or 127.0.0.1):8888/
[I 17:48:59.389 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

#### I don't know what the problem is.I've searched a lot,but just cannot find a solution.

### Any suggestions will be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. It's because my server's 9999 port is not opening to the Internet.